# Ensure parent models are the same for a has_many :through association in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, associations

I have a `Department` parent model that is associated with a `Product` and `Document` model through a `has_many` / `belongs_to` relationship. The `Product` and `Document` models are then associated to each other through a `has_many :through` relationship via a `ProductDocuments` join model.

As part of the associations there is a requirement that the `Product` and `Document` models have the same `Department` parent model when being associated to each other.

Right now I'm doing the following:

```
ProductDocumentsController < ApplicationController
    ...
    def create
        @product = Product.find(params[:product_document][:product_id])
        @document = Document.find(params[:product_document][:document_id])

        if @product.department.id == @document.department.id
            ...
        end
    end
    ...
end
```

This works, however it feels inefficient as it introduces two addition database calls in the controller.

Does anyone know of a way that this can be accomplished in a more efficient way, perhaps through a validation in the model?

Any help would be greatly appreciated; thank you!

Comment: "that the Product and Document models have the same Product parent model when being associated to each other". You mean "same Department"?

Comment: @marvelousNinja I did indeed, thank you for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are my thoughts. Get pencil, paper and draw with me =). I've ended up with something like  this.

```
Department * * * Product
*                   *
*                   *
*                   *
Document * * * ProductDocument
```

And that is something called *circular reference*. Typically it leads to cases like yours - complex validations of field equality among possibly infinite number of tables. So, how do we fix it?

Couple of variants:

1. Simply break one of the links. For example, `Document` will reference to `Product` alone.
2. Remove references to `Department` from both `Product` and `Document`, and put it somewhere else. For example, into `ProductDocument` (however, it's going to be renamed to something more appropriate since it will join three models).

That's all I can say for now.