# Rails - Associations conditions between models

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have three models: host, service and environment.

```
environment
  has_many :hosts
  has_many :services

host
  has_many :services
  belongs_to :environment

service
  belongs_to :host
  belongs_to :environment
```

There is two env, pre and pro.
Hosts and services could be in any env.

The problem is that I want to define that a service in, for instance, 'pre' env, only could belong to a host in the same env.

I think that has to be somthing like

```
has_many :services, :conditions => proc  { "host.environment_id=service.environment_id" }
```

But don't know how to do it.

Using Rails 4.0.2 and Ruby 2.0.0p299

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is - that condition won't block you from actually associating record with wrong (i.e. different `environment_id`). You can consult docs [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).That condition only matters during querying. You need some kind of validation on one of your models. Something like:

```
validates :same_environment

def for_same_environment
  host.environment_id == service.environment_id
end
```

However, here's a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21736409/ensure-parent-models-are-the-same-for-a-has-many-through-association-in-rails-3/21737253#21737253) to one of my previous posts. Maybe you will consider to change a schema a bit.